# Ошибка mysql SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054]

Tags: php, mysql

При попытки подключения к MySQL из PHP Yii2, да и просто из PHP методом PDO Происходит ошибка: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

Версии ПО:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux CentOS7VMware 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 16:44:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)


$ php-fpm -v
PHP 7.2.11 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Oct 10 2018 10:03:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies


$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2


$ ./yii
This is Yii version 2.0.15.1.
```

Вот код из PHP:

```
$mysqlConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic", "zrt", "Ah$%s74sDKGDH");
```

И конфиг Yii2:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'zrt',
    'password' => 'Ah$%s74sDKGDH',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

**Вообще зачем нужна такая ошибка и как это все победить?**

Answer (score 1):

В восьмой версии mysql изменена система соединения с сервером. Насколько я знаю PHP еще не поддерживает новый плагин `caching_sha2_password`. Для работы вам нужно настроить файл конфигурации mysql, то есть изменить плагин аутентификации на старый.

```
...
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
...
```

https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/ можете почитать здесь, тут все предельно ясно объясняют.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY '';
```