# Ошибка обращения к базе данных в Laravel. В чём причина?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

При попытке обращения к базе данных получаю ошибку:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from users where id = :id)**

Прошу совета: в чём проблема и как исправить?

- Система: Windows 10
- MySQL: 8.0
- PHP: 7.4.1
- laravel: 5.0.1
- extension=pdo_mysql
- [mysqld] default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function getUsers()
    {
        $results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
    }
}
```

**config.inc.php**

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  $i++;
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '1234'; 
?>
```

**database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('shop', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('root', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('1234', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
],
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Comment: Да собственно именно в том, что и написано - текущий коннектор не поддерживает дефолтный метод шифрования сервера. Или обновляй версию коннектора, или меняй метод криптования пароля для своей учётной записи.

Comment: Как? Где об этом можно прочитать?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+server+requested+authentication+method+unknown+to+the+client)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пытался обойти эту проблему, но не смог. В качестве решения ранее выставил `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`, но это не помогло (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913213/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-mysql-sqlstatehy000-2054). Вероятно, я не сделал как правильно. Если вы сможете подсказать, что конкретно нужно изменить в конфигах, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Нет, всё правильно. Но для пользователя, уже существующего, пароль уже применён с использованием SHA2. Так что его надо пересоздать (или изменить, если это допустимо на твоей версии) - с указанием именно для него опции нативного пароля.

Comment: Только что понял, что ответил неправильно выше. Т.е. проблему пытался решить, но mysql_native_password у меня стоял изначально в настройках конфигурации.

Comment: В любом случае - ошибка это нередкая (поищи ещё на SO.EN и на DBA.SO), и вроде как всегда решаемая. Просто надо просмотреть не одну, а горсть тем, постараться опознать по симптомам именно свой кейс, и применить решение именно для твоего случая.

Comment: У вас проболемы в конфиге

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените часть конфига

```
'database' => env('shop', 'forge'),
'username' => env('root', 'forge'),
'password' => env('1234', ''),
```

на

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @118_64, дефолтные значения идут вторым аргументом в `env()`